# using List of <bool function, procedure to execute name> instead of using if/switch

Tags: c#

I am looking for an implementation similar to following:

Having the conditions to be checked and the corresponding code to be executed in a List of `<Function , Procedure Name to Execute >`, and then using LINQ , getting the list of `<Procedure Name to Execute>` and calling them in Parallel.

Is there a name for this kind of programming rather than using coded if/switch ?
Is there some library/framework/pattern that uses something similar to above?

PS: using LINQ is not a requirement, I am probably just fishing here for ideas and existing codes that I can use.

Comment: What? I think your English is getting in the way of comprehension on this one. Could you provide some pseudo-code perhaps?

Comment: Do you want to execute them by *name* as in a string; or by delegate / methodgroup?

Comment: I think I understand vaguely what you're talking about, but your actual question is unclear. Do you want to know what it's called? Do you want an example of how to do it? Are you asking about libraries that implement it?

Comment: I feel like you want something like a `Dictionary<string, Action>()`

Comment: It's basically a container like pattern which hold the name and the functions and you match an alias / name in the hashtable key to get the stored function for execution.  I used this pattern to reduce switch / if previously where a factory will use the container to gain access to the corresponding strategy / command to use and so the only case / select / if is internalized in the factory pattern and the rest just don't need to know about specifics, just the interface.

Comment: @JimmyChandra Errr.... was that a clarification or what you actually use?

Comment: Used it previously.  Actually implementation is to store the concrete implementation of the interface, in this case a strategy (it could as easily be a `Func<>` or `Action<>` -- don't matter) in DI container.  Hooked up my factory to the DI. Have `switch` statement in the `CreateFor(enumType)` and basically delegate the creation to the DI container and just call the interface method to get what I want.  Nothing to do w/ parallel execution but it uses similar pattern.

Comment: I do love it when someone asks a question then disappears before answering any questions in the comments...

Comment: @Jonesy : Nop, want something similar to Guffa's answer

Comment: @Blorgbeard : I would like to either approach, and being able to do one or the other until I can understand their pros and cons of each method.

Comment: @Steve : Is that because Lisp is homoiconici?

Comment: @JimmyChandra :  I like that apprach too, can we see some code if possible, or some refrence to what type of programming is this called please?

Comment: Here is an example... the name is just made up.  I don't really know if there is any actual pattern name for this... https://dotnetfiddle.net/ugqeK5

Comment: @Arjang yes.  LISP natively provides the relation between names and functions he is looking for.  Since he wants to parallelize the evaluation of each list item then a parallel flavor of LISP would be useful, but it would remove the determinism of list evaluation.  BTW, I am a C# developer who has recently been working on a LISP interpreter.

Comment: @JimmyChandra : Thank you again for your idea, do you have links or blogs that you like? Do you have blog of your own? Anyone coming up with solutions like yours is worth following and learning a lot from.

Comment: I only use my blog to remind myself of stuffs, mostly work related, haven't much time to update it lately, blog.jimmychandra.com. Twits @jchandra.  Blog that I follow hmm... not lately, but I listened to podcast a lot such as DotNetRocks, Hanselminutes, JavaScript Jabbr, Adventure in Angular, Herding Code, etc.  to keep up to date as well as following online webcasts like Channel9 events, NDC on vimeo, and youtube channels like ngconf, jsconf, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a list of tuples containing functions for the conditions and corresponding code. From that you can easily select the functions to run and use `AsParallel` to run them.

Example:

```
var tools = new List<Tuple<Func<int, bool>, Func<int, string>>>();

tools.Add(new Tuple<Func<int, bool>, Func<int, string>>(
  n => n > 0,
  n => n + " is greater than 0"
));
tools.Add(new Tuple<Func<int, bool>, Func<int, string>>(
  n => n < 0,
  n => n + " is less than 0"
));
tools.Add(new Tuple<Func<int, bool>, Func<int, string>>(
  n => n == 4,
  n => n + " is four"
));
tools.Add(new Tuple<Func<int, bool>, Func<int, string>>(
  n => n % 2 == 1,
  n => n + " is odd"
));

int value = 3;

List<string> results = tools
  .Where(t => t.Item1(value))
  .AsParallel()
  .Select(t => t.Item2(value))
  .ToList();
```

In the example I used lambda expressions also to supply the work to be run in parallel, but you can of course use the name of a method instead. You would hardly cram any code that would actually need parallelising into a lambda expression.